# Jquery - How to validate email that is inside a span

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a `span` that is generated every time a user `focus out` in the textbox. 
This `span` will contain emails so I want to validate every time a user enters an email. How can I apply a validation in jquery throught this span?

Below is my code

```
$('#tags input').on('focusout',function(){    
            var i = 0;
            var txt = $.trim( this.value );
            if(txt) {
                $(this).before('<span class="tag" id="">'+txt+'</span>');
            }
                this.value = "";
        });
```

Comment: ...by running the validation against `txt`? If you're looking for a validation function, one of these [**many** answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) may help you.

Comment: @ObsidianAge thanks dude, it fixed!